# C# Parse value if not null

Tags: c#, parsing, null

Here's something that's not really an issue and I apologize if it's a stupid question but it's just something I'm curious about. Let's say I want to parse a string parameter as an integer if the string is not null, otherwise set the integer to -1. Is there a better way to write this statement:

```
int id = context.Request["Id"] == null ? -1 : int.Parse(context.Request["Id"]);
```

It just seems messy to have to evaluate the string to see if it's null and then evaluate it again to parse it. Now that I think about it, this has come up with objects and accessing an objects properties if it isn't null. So something like:

```
int id = person == null ? -1 : person.id;
```

Is this the accepted practice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your first example, you can use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
int id = int.Parse(context.Request["Id"] ?? "-1");
```

For your second example, you can use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
int id = person?.Id ?? -1;
```

Comment: This does cause an unnecessary `int.Parse("-1")`, though, instead of just setting the value to -1 directly.

Comment: I didn't even think to make the null check while passing the parameter into the parse method, doh! It seems so simple now. And yes the null-safe dereferencing operator is exactly what I was looking for, good to know that it exists, just not for C#. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You didn't state whether `int.Parse()` has the potential to fail for non-null values, but if you aren't certain a non-null input string will always be an `int` value, you can also use the `TryParse()` method:

```
int id;
if (!int.TryParse(context.Request["Id"], out id)
    id = -1;
```

This will not throw an exception if `context.Request["Id"]` is null, or if it is not parsable to `int`.

Comment: that looks exaclty like my answer :) Seems like we were typing the same chars at exaclty the same moment.

Comment: anyway +1 for this, as it is much better to be prepared for non-numeric input instead of catching an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would make this two statements:

```
string tmp = context.Request["Id"];
int id = String.IsNullOrWhitespace(tmp) ? -1 : int.Parse(tmp);
```

This handles this without any extra parsing.  Doing this in one line will require an extra lookup of the context (which you were trying to avoid) or extra parsing.

Comment: IsNullOrWhitespace? and what with everything else that isn't a number? int.TryParse seems a better solution to me.

Comment: @WouterH Yes - this doesn't handle non-numeric input - but it was really more a matter of trying to address the specific question regarding handling nulls vs. int parsing.